# Event repetition of ng-fullcalender not working in angular

Tags: node.js, angular5

Am working on ng-fullcalender package in angular.till now working fine.i want to repeat the event on specific days/month.In fullcalender documentation they says use dow:[2] it works fine when using fullcalender with jquery.problem is that am using fullcalender package in angular.so am stuck in that problem.i dont know how we do event repetition in angular5.thanks inAdvance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please have a look at [**asking help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise your post

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).